# Type() -> Int cannot conform to BinaryInteger

Tags: swift

I am trying to find the number of item bigger than a certain item as follows. However, I am getting the following issue : `Type() -> Int cannot conform to BinaryInteger`.

I am wondering how I could able to fix it?

```
extension Array where Element: FloatingPoint {
       

   var biggerItem : Element {
       return numberBiggerItems()
   }

   private func numberBiggerItems() -> Element {
      return Element { filter({$0 > 100.0}).count }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems in your code:

- The return type of your method should be `Int`, which is what the`count` of a collection returns.
- The literal `100.0` is interpreted as a `Double`. You have to use `100` so that it can be a literal for the generic `FloatingPoint` type.
- The return value of `filter(...).count` must not be wrapped in a closure (this is what causes the seen error message).

Putting it together:

```
extension Array where Element: FloatingPoint {
    
    var biggerItem : Int {
        return numberBiggerItems()
    }
    
    private func numberBiggerItems() -> Int {
        return filter({ $0 > 100 }).count
    }
}
```

If you really want to return the integer count as an `Element` then it can be converted with an `Element(...)` constructor:

```
extension Array where Element: FloatingPoint {
    
    var biggerItem : Element {
        return numberBiggerItems()
    }
    
    private func numberBiggerItems() -> Element {
        return Element(filter({ $0 > 100 }).count)
    }
}
```